# More public member functions than those strictly required by the C++ standard

Tags: c++, std

I see a public `std::istream_iterator::_M_equal` member function in my C++ implementation (it is used to compare istream iterators by other standard global functions). The standard does not require that member function to be available to the user.

I would like to know if implementations providing more public member functions other than those required by the standard can still be considered "standard".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed by the standard.

The required interface is described by the standard document, but generally not the exact way to implement it. Names starting with underscore+uppercase letter, like `_M_equal`, are specifically reserved to the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Only those api/feature mandated by the C++ Standard should be supported by Standard conforming implementations are standard, implementations are free to add their own extensions but they are non standard and non portable because other implementations are not required to support those.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's allowed. Since you're not allowed to define any of your own names inside the `std` namespace, and since moreover names with underscore-capital are reserved, there is no chance that a well-formed C++ program can experience a name conflict with those implementation details.

Obviously no portable program must use those additional public functions, although nothing is stopping you from using them on *your* specific platform.